# Why is my background image keep shrinking when I resize the browser

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design

When resizing the browser or testing the responsiveness through devtools, the background image tends to shrink and move towards the left and when it reaches to a width like 600px the image only takes up half of the div, I looked around, and everyone suggest background-size: cover;, but that's not working. What am I doing wrong? How can I make it so that the image always covers the div?

```
#page-header {
    
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background-image: url(an-image.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-origin: border-box;
    display:flex;
    align-content: center;
    
    }
```

Comment: Is the div itself filling the whole width of the page? `background-size: cover` will make the background image scale by maintaining aspect to fill the whole div, so if it's not filling the whole width of the page, my guess is the div itself isn't filling the whole width of the page.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you are wanting to do as you have margin: 0 auto and width 100%. Also, is the width of the parent element set at all?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `height:700px` and the `background-image`, your image will not occupy 100% of your width, but 700px of your height.

You have to use the `<img/>` tag.
For exemple, add to #page-header `position:relative;` and `overflow:hidden;`. Then, add an `img` tag child (with the src attribute) with those properties:

```
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
```